# Добавить дорожное событие на Яндекс.Карте (или в Навигаторе)

Tags: android, сеть, яндекс-карты, мобильные-приложения

Всем привет!
Необходимо программно добавить дорожное событие на Яндекс.Карте в конкретной точке.
Т.е. есть координаты (широта-долгота), нужно сделать так, чтобы в этой точке появилось сообщение или ДТП, камера и пр. С нужным текстом. Как на картинке, в общем.

[image: Картинка]

**Как это сделать?**
Пытался использовать снифферы на телефоне (Android), не получается что-то у меня... :(
Подскажите, как это можно сделать? Куда копать? Или может, кто-то уже делал нечто подобное?
API у Яндекса, насколько я понимаю, на это дело закрыто...

Запрограммировать я смогу, надо определить GET/POST-запрос, заголовки...
Может, авторизация там нужна?